# How was Hodor named as so?

Tags: game-of-thrones, a-song-of-ice-and-fire, names

We know that he can only say his name. I observed from the series that whenever he is spoken to, he replies with:

> Hodor!

or

> Hodor.

Is this how he was named? Or did someone give him Hodor as a name and then he replied:

> Hodor!

Comment: No, he also says (and I quote) *"Hodor?"* To which, by the way, Bran gives him the most approriate reply, *"Hodor"*. Further, you also seem to forget this much more extensive reply he provides to Theon at one point *"Hodor hodor hodor hodor"*, and this very imaginative song of his, *"Hodor, hodor, hodor"*. Further there is also the quote *"Hooooooodor, hoooooodor, hoDOR, hoDOR, hoDOR."* though, granted, that seems to be more of a random muttering than actual speech. :)

Comment: See also http://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/90400/4918 "Why or how did Smeagol's “name” became Gollum?"

Answer (score 16, accepted):

We already knew that his real name wasn't Hodor, but Walder (books) and Wylis (TV Show). We learn the origin of "Hodor" in the 5th episode of the 6th season.

**SPOILERS FOR S06E05:**

> We see that  when Meera, Hodor and Bran are trying to exit the cave in order to escape the Night King and his army, Meera is carrying Bran on the sledge and tells Hodor to "**Hold the Door**" over and over, in order to prevent the White Walkers from exiting the cave and catching up to them. 
>
>  While this is happening, Bran is viewing the past and inadvertently warged into Wylis (Hodor's real name), thus linking the present day Hodor with young Wylis. Hodor then has a fit and falls to the ground, while shouting "Hold the door" repeatedly. He gradually removes some words (Hold the door -> Hold door -> Hodor) and that is how he started saying Hodor. 
>  [Scene link.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AHMTVcbvb3c)

There is also an 'Inside the Episode':

Where David Benioff says that this is in fact the same origin for the name as in the books.

Comment: @Skooba You've got a point there, but in the question itself he doesn't specify if he wanted a strictly book answer

Comment: +1 And to give even more credibility, include the [Inside the Episode #5](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=X9Jsj9V_Aqg). Starting from 5:20 David Benioff talks about the meeting with George R.R. Martin. And says that the meaning of the name Hodor comes directly from the book author. No surprise that I liked the scene the most. Seems like Hold the door = Hodor will be also in the Books. With this information the answer perfectly firs the ASOIAF tag.

Comment: @Skooba in an interview from 2014 the interviewer told GRRM he has a theory on Hodor's name, that it means "hold the door", and GRRM laughed and said " *(laughter)* You don’t know how close to the truth you are!"

Comment: @Petersaber Just stumbled across this page, do you have a link to that interview still? Seems it might be an interesting read.

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot I misremembered what it was (but not the quote. Weird) - https://ventrellaquest.com/2014/04/20/got-got/